# How can I make a real purchase from my webapp from localhost:4200?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe checkout in an angular app. When I make a purchase from my app running in localhost using my stripe test account, everything works fine. When I switch to a production client token, my request is denied by stripe. The message says that localhost is not whitelisted for my account. I went to my account dashboard and tried to add localhost but it wouldn't allow it.

Does anyone know how to make this happen. I want to do some testing on my localhost making real purchases before i publish my app.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe Checkout with your live mode keys only works over HTTPS (or security reasons [0]), it works in localhost only in test mode.

You should swap in your live mode keys only when you are ready for production and have your web page/app deployed.

There is a handy checklist that you can reference so that you're meeting all the requirements before going live [1]

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/security#tls

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/live